# How to check for duplicates in a string but not replace them?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sample user input

```
letters = input("Please input the scrambled letters in order: ")
```

Now we all know that there are only 26 letter in english and none of them repeat. So how do I make sure that whatever the user inputs doesn't repeat(don't need to replace)? I need to write an if statement with that algorithm.

```
if letters == nothing_duplicate:
    do something
```

Comment: By duplicate what do you mean? Duplicated characters?

Comment: Yes. Like ABCDDE... - D is repeated twice. I need to validate this and make sure that the entry is only once. So only if the input is ABCD.. continue with the program.

Comment: Looks like homework.  Hint, use `set`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if len(letters) == len(set(letters)):
    do something
```

Comment: This works because `set` can only have one value assigned per index. Thus if there are repeated characters, only one instance will be in the set (which accounts for the length difference)

Comment: Very Pythonic. Upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for duplicates **and** verify that they have input every letter:

```
import string
if set(letters.lower()) == set(string.lowercase):
  # do something
```

To actually get the list of letters that are missing, you could do something like this:

```
>>> set(string.lowercase).difference('abcdefghijklmnopqrst')
set(['u', 'w', 'v', 'y', 'x', 'z'])
```